# textfield text leaves an impression on other textfiled when tableview is scrolled

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uikit, uitextfield

Hi guys I have custom `tableview` `cells` called `product cell,rating cell,notify cell`,where `product cell` contains `textfield` where it used in `section 0,1,2,4`. the problem is if I input a text in the `textfileds` present in `section 0`. when scrolled I ve left with an text impressions on the `textfileds` present in `section1,2`..could u guys help me out.below is the code

```
  -(ProductCell *)getProductCell
{
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    ProductCell  *cell;
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[ProductCell  class]])
        {
            cell= (ProductCell*)currentObject;
            return cell;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
-(RatingCell *)getRatingCell
{
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RatingCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    RatingCell  *cell;
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[RatingCell  class]])
        {
            cell= (RatingCell*)currentObject;
            return cell;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

-(NotifyCell *)getNotifyCell
{
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NotifyCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    NotifyCell  *cell;
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[NotifyCell  class]])
        {
            cell= (NotifyCell *)currentObject;
            return cell;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier3 = @"Cell3";

    ProductCell *productCell;
    NotifyCell *notifyCell;
    productCell=(ProductCell *)[tblAddProducts dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
    notifyCell = (NotifyCell*)[tblAddProducts dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];


    UINib * nib1 = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ProductCell" bundle: nil];
    [tableView registerNib:nib1 forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

    UINib * nib2 = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NotifyCell" bundle: nil];
    [tableView registerNib:nib2 forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

    UINib * nib3 = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"RatingCell" bundle: nil];
   [tableView registerNib:nib3 forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier3];


    if (notifyCell == nil)
    {
    notifyCell = [self getNotifyCell];
    }
    if (ratingCell == nil)
    {
    ratingCell = [self getRatingCell];
    }
    if (productCell == nil)
    {
        productCell = [self getProductCell];
    }


    productCell.txtField.delegate=self;
    productCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    notifyCell.selectionStyle  = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    ratingCell.selectionStyle  = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
        productCell.lblName.text=[productTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        productCell.txtField.tag=indexPath.row;

        if([productCell.lblName.text isEqualToString:@"Valid till"]) productCell.txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        else productCell.txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
        cellSection = indexPath.section;
        return productCell;
        break;

        case 1:
        productCell.lblName.text=[invoiceTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        productCell.txtField.tag=indexPath.row;
        if ([productCell.lblName.text isEqualToString:@"Bank Name"]) productCell.txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        else productCell.txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
        cellSection = indexPath.section;
        return productCell;
        break;

        case 2:
        productCell.lblName.text=[warrantyTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        productCell.txtField.tag=indexPath.row;
        if ([productCell.lblName.text isEqualToString:@"Valid till"]) productCell.txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        else productCell.txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
        cellSection = indexPath.section;
        return productCell;
        break;

        case 3:
        productCell.lblName.text=@"Description";
        productCell.txtField.tag=indexPath.row;
        if ([productCell.lblName.text isEqualToString:@"Description"]) productCell.txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        cellSection = indexPath.section;
        return productCell;
        break;

        case 4:
        ratingCell.lblName.text=@"Rating";
        ratingCell.starRatingControl.delegate=self;
        cellSection = indexPath.section;
        return ratingCell;
        break;

        case 5:
        productCell.lblName.text=[serviceContactsTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        productCell.txtField.tag=indexPath.row;
        if ([productCell.lblName.text isEqualToString:@"Email"]) productCell.txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        else productCell.txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
        cellSection = indexPath.section;
        return productCell;
        break;

        case 6:
        notifyCell.lblName.text=[notifyTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cellSection = indexPath.section;
        return notifyCell;
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
    productCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return productCell;
    }
```

Comment: Either you have all the `UITextfields` connected to the same `IBOutlet`..

Comment: yeah ...if u want i cud give u the entire code..

Comment: no i wont require the complete code.. you can just check it yourself on how you have connected the IBOutlets for tableViewCell

Comment: i ve got a textfield in my custom cell named as product cell which is reused in different section of tableview and there is only one connection

Comment: The text field might be reused by the table view because of the method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.

Comment: thats is why when you type something in one textfield it copies the text in other textfields.. so either you should give them a tag or create separate outlets for them. The Tagging work is preferred.

Comment: @verbumdei..u right the cells are getting reused ...donno how to solve dat

Comment: @ahmed:how d use tag in the above code ...?

Comment: set Reusable identifier to nil in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 0):

Your table view cells are being reused. This is the way table view cells are being optimized.

If you know exactly how many sections and rows the table view has and they will not change, consider using static table view cells which is also suitable for forms:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Look at the section *The Technique for Static Row Content*.

Otherwise you will need to save the value of each text field into a variable, such as rating, email, description, and put it back to the text field every time the respective table view cell is loaded.

Comment: could u help me solve dis if i give u entire source code...because i m using multiple custom cells ...